# Ошибка TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, type-error

Начинаю изучать питон, столкнулся с такой проблемой как TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. Прошу помощи, т.к. перерыл все похожие вопросы и ничего не понял.
Задача, которую я решаю:

Имеется набор данных, состоящий из пар положительных целых чисел. Необходимо выбрать из каждой пары ровно одно число так, чтобы сумма всех выбранных чисел не делилась на 4 и при этом была максимально возможной. Если получить требуемую сумму невозможно, в качестве ответа нужно выдать 0.

```py
n = int(input())
a = [0] * 4
b = [0] * 4
r = c = 0
for i in range(n):
    s = input().split()
    s[0] = int(s[0])
    s[1] = int(s[1])
    for j in range(len(a)):
        a[j] = 0
    for k in range(2):
        for p in range(len(a)):
            r = (b[p] + s[k]) % 4
            if a[r] < (b[p] + s[k]):
                a = b[p] + s[k]
    b = a
print(max(a[1], a[2], a[3]))
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки. А именно, в какой строке она произошла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно быть внимательнее с именами переменных и что они означают. Давать переменным имена из одной буквы - очень плохо (допустимо разве что в качестве итератора в цикле, да и то лучше и там так не делать), сам потом забудешь где что.

В строчке `a = b[p] + s[k]` переменная `а` из списка превращается в число и на второй итерации в стрчоке `if a[r] < (b[p] + s[k]):` возникает ошибка, потому что `a[r]` становится недопустимой операцией.

Точно такая же ошибка возникнет на второй итерации внешнего цикла в строчке r = `(b[p] + s[k]) % 4` потому что строка `b = a` делает из списка `b` число.